# Is it possible to update the built-in OpenSSH Client in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, powershell, openssh

I'm experiencing certain issues with the built-in OpenSSH client that, according to the [Win32-OpenSSH Github](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) page, seem resolved in newer versions. The newest version is v7.9 while the preinstalled client is in version 7.6p1.

```
PS C:\> ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
```

I understand it's possible to install OpenSSH both as an optional feature in the "apps & features" settings page, or using Powershell. That seems futile in my situation as the client clearly already is installed.

```
PS C:\>  Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to update the client this way and the Github page doesn't seem to publish binaries. Does this mean I have to make the binaries myself if I want to use newer versions, and would they even work as a replacement not being signed or anything? Is there maybe a simpler way?

Comment: I had the same problem. Since I have the Windows Subsystem for Linux installed, I just switched to using `wsl -e ssh` instead of `ssh`, which executes the (newer) version of ssh inside the Linux subsystem.

Answer (score 16):

This [page](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/How-to-retrieve-links-to-latest-packages) gives the steps to follow using Powershell to install the latest packages.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$url = 'https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/latest/'
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$request.AllowAutoRedirect=$false
$response=$request.GetResponse()
$([String]$response.GetResponseHeader("Location")).Replace('tag','download') + '/OpenSSH-Win64.zip'  
$([String]$response.GetResponseHeader("Location")).Replace('tag','download') + '/OpenSSH-Win32.zip'
```

If you use Chocolatey, then type the following in the command prompt as shown [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/openssh):

```
choco upgrade openssh
```

Comment: You will likely want to use the instructions on this [page](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) to install the update.  However, I would perform test within a virtual machine, to verify what actually happens.  Unless there is a vulnerability you are specifically worried about, you might not want to attempt to manually update the install, and instead, remove the built-in version and use the above installation instructions.

Comment: I needed to change $request.AllowAutoRedirect=$false to $request.AllowAutoRedirect=$true

Comment: Both don't do much, at least don't give any output and afterwards (even after opening a new shell) `ssh -V` just gives me the same output: `OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5`

Answer (score 15):

The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1555453/388906) to overwrite the files works:

> Download the latest and update them in C:\Windows\System32.

However, this is easier said than done due to how Windows restricts permissions to modify/write files in System32. Running PowerShell as Administrator was not sufficient to modify files. I had to change ownership and add full control permissions to get it done as follows:

```
# Download upstream bins
$url = 'https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/latest/'
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$request.AllowAutoRedirect=$false
$response=$request.GetResponse()
$source = $([String]$response.GetResponseHeader("Location")).Replace('tag','download') + '/OpenSSH-Win64.zip'
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($source, 'OpenSSH-Win64.zip')



# Overwrite windows installed bins
$openSshBins = (Get-ChildItem 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\').Name
Expand-Archive -Path .\OpenSSH-Win64.zip -DestinationPath .
takeown.exe /a /r /f C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
icacls.exe 'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH' /grant 'BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)F'
icacls.exe 'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH' /grant 'BUILTIN\Administrators:F' /t
Stop-Service ssh-agent
$openSshBins | %{ Copy-Item -Path .\OpenSSH-Win64\$_ -Destination C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ }
Start-Service ssh-agent
```

Note, to auotmate the download, you need to permit redirects.

Comment: download automation is broken again :(

Comment: Thanks, corrected and disabled redirects again. Not sure why, could swear that last time I had to have redirects enabled for it to work for me.

Comment: I got the following on the last command: 

`Start-Service : Service 'OpenSSH Authentication Agent (ssh-agent)' cannot be started due to the following error:
Cannot start service ssh-agent on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service ssh-agent
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand`

Comment: @StevenLu That error is probably caused by startup type is disabled for ssh authentication agent. see https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1625

Comment: "Download upstream bins" part fails. After downloading OpenSSH-Win64.zip from 
 https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/v8.9.1.0p1-Beta,  use the "# Overwrite windows installed bins" part works.
(write that part to a file like any_name.ps1,   in pwsh as admin  ,  issue  `&  any_name.ps1` )

Comment: If you are still interesting in maintaining; the newest version also needs to copy libcrypto.dll from the zip to the system32 folder which your script skips

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/2052

Answer (score 14):

1. Remove the default version of OpenSSH:

```
Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
```

2. Install the recent version:

- using Windows Package Manager:

  ```
  winget install openssh-beta
  ```
- manually from GitHub (see [Install Win32 OpenSSH Using MSI](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH-Using-MSI))

3. Add it to path:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", 
$env:Path + ';' + ${Env:ProgramFiles} + '\OpenSSH', 
[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Comment: To avoid installing the server (`sshd`), add an installation argument: `winget install Microsoft.OpenSSH.Beta --override ADDLOCAL=Client` --- Note `Microsoft.OpenSSH.Beta` is the full name of the package.

Comment: Just found out, when installing client only, the `ssh-agent` service is also unavailable.

Comment: The package id is `Microsoft.OpenSSH.Beta` and the moniker is `openssh-beta`.

Comment: Running `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0` adds the  latest OpenSSH. Keep in mind that it has an issue that have [a workaround](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/2052#issuecomment-1692140847).

Answer (score 6):

The binaries are now on [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/). Download the latest and update them in C:\Windows\System32.