# Version information and update for OpenSSH for Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, openssh

I wanted to update the pre-installed version of `OpenSSH for Windows` on `Windows 1903`, since that one, `7.2p1` had some issues which had reportedly been fixed on `v 8.0.0.0`.

I followed the guide and links as given on  - 
[Update OpenSSH for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1395962/is-it-possible-to-update-the-built-in-openssh-client-in-windows-10), and subsequently did a
[Powershell update](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH).

However, when typing `ssh -V` in Powershell, I get, 
`OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1`, and not `8.0.0.0` as I was expecting. I checked the environment variables, they all pointed to the correct location of `OpenSSH` binary folder within `Program Files`. The earlier version had been in a different place, which is no longer there.

When I try and get the File version of the `sshd` service installed, I get `8.0.0.0`, but `ssh -V` still returns `7.7p1`. Should I be concerned about this version mismatch?

Comment: `sshd` is the server / daemon `ssh` is the client. Maybe that's where the difference comes from

Answer (score 5):

I got the same version mismatch. I *was* concerned because it appeared that the SSH sessions I was initiating were using 7.7, and not 8.0. To fix it, I uninstalled openssh from Settings > Apps > Optional Features, and then installed the new Git-based version with chocolatey:

**choco install openssh**

Then, an **ssh -V** returned 8.0. Didn't fix my particular problem, but it did fix the version mismatch!
Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same "issue"
You need to check where ssh is pointing to.
`get-command ssh | select name,path` will let you know where ssh.exe is located.

```
Name                                 Path
----                                 ---- 
ssh.exe                              C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
```

in my case it was pointing to

> C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe

so I updated git, checked system variable PATH and now it shows latest version

```
ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

Comment: That isn’t the correct path for the OpenSSH Client optional Windows Feature.  You have simply installed OpenSSH that comes along with Git.  This was not actually the author’s question, they made not mention of using Git, installing Git doesn’t update the OpenSSH they already have installed

Comment: You didn’t install the Microsoft port of OpenSSH if it’s installed in the directory you specified.

Comment: `Get-Command ssh`

_C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe_

`Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -eq 'sshd'} | select Name, DisplayName, State, PathName`
_sshd OpenSSH SSH Server Stopped "C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\OpenSSH-Win64\sshd.exe"_

install-sshd.ps1 does not include ssh.exe file update.it is only updating sshd and ssh-agent services.

Comment: That still isn’t the correct path for OpenSSH when it’s installed through Optional Windows Feature.