# Use SSH key signing with Git and ssh-agent under Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, git, openssh

### Situation

I'm using Git 2.34 under Windows with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` set to Windows OpenSSH implementation (it's also set on `PATH`). I want to use the new Git SSH key commit signing feature in combination with ssh-agent.

I added my ed25519 key to ssh-agent and `ssh-add -L` prints the proper key. Derived from that output, I use this in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[gpg]
    format = ssh
[user]
    signingkey = ssh-ed25519 mykeyhere
```

When trying to sign a commit, this error message shows up:

```
error: Load key "C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/.git_signing_key_tmp8eWdG0": invalid format?
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I validated that the contents of `.git_signing_key_tmp8eWdG0` are correct (also in UTF-8 without BOM). I debugged Git with `GIT_TRACE=1` and it shows it uses this command line which produces the error:

```
run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: ssh-keygen -Y sign -n git -f 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp/.git_signing_key_tmp8eWdG0' 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp/.git_signing_buffer_tmp8eWdG0'
```

But executing the very same command from the debug output above (the `ssh-keygen` one) manually works:

```
C:\>ssh-keygen -vvv -Y sign -n git -f C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp/.git_signing_key_tmp8eWdG0 test.txt
Signing file test.txt
debug2: hash_file: hashed 4 bytes
debug3: hash_file: final hash: ee26b0dd4af7e749aa1a8ee3c10ae9923f618980772e473f8819a5d4940e0db27ac185f8a0e1d5f84f88bc887fd67b143732c304cc5fa9ad8e6f57f50028a8ff
Write signature to test.txt.sig
```

So I got curious and removed OpenSSH from `PATH` and re-ran the commit procedure and it still shows the signing error despite `ssh-keygen` is not available anymore:

```
C:\>where ssh-keygen
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

This proves that Git is using some `ssh-keygen` command which seems to be incompatible with the Windows OpenSSH binary (which would work as shown) but I can't find this binary Git is using nor can I find a way to modify the used binary (even though `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` is set correctly and is used for all other purposes like pushing).

I am having this problem on `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe`. I am not using the Git bash.

### Questions

1. How can I fix my problem?
2. How can I find out which `ssh-keygen` Git is using?
3. How can I change the `ssh-keygen` Git is using?
4. How can I get more verbose error output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution (discussed [on GitHub](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3647#issuecomment-1021478482)):

1. Reinstall git with "Use external OpenSSH" (untick "Only show new options" during the installation start)
2. Update Window's OpenSSH to 8.6; ([repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH), [tutorial](https://superuser.com/a/1609071/187633)); without it it showed `Unsupported certificate option "verify-time=20220125190555"` when browsing commits with `git show --show-signature`