# Windows Subsystem for Linux: error fetching identities: communication with agent failed with keys from KeepassXC

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, keepassxc

My ssh keys are stored in KeepassXC (version 2.7.1). I've enabled the SSH Agent integration in KeepassXC and have it use OpenSSH. I tried using Pageant and with "Use both agents" but it doesn't work as it fails to connect to the ssh agent. The KeepassXC is installed on my Windows 10.

I have OpenSSH Authentication Agent running, started and on automatic. With all of this setup, I can see that the keys are loaded by doing `ssh-add -l` in my powershell.

Following the README guide from this repo https://github.com/rupor-github/wsl-ssh-agent, I have:

- Installed `socat` in WSL2
- Installed `wsl-ssh-agent.exe` and running in Windows 10.
- Stored `npiperelay.exe` in Windows 10 partition (currently in Documents folder).
- And added to the bottom of my `.zshrc` file:

```bsh
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$HOME/.ssh/agent.sock

ss -a | grep -q $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        rm -f $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
        (setsid socat UNIX-LISTEN:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK,fork EXEC:"/mnt/c/Users/myusername/Documents/wsl-ssh-agent/npiperelay.exe -ei -s //./pipe/openssh-ssh-agent",nofork &) >/dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

- Ran and restarted my shell with `exec zsh` or closed and reopened my terminal and tested with `ssh-add -l` but I get this error message:

`error fetching identities: communication with agent failed`

I have also tried restarting my KeepassXC and OpenSSH agent service, same error. But I can confirm that the keys are still loaded via my powershell with `ssh-add -l`.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:
My WSL2 is a Debian.

```sh
> cat /etc/debian_version
11.3
> ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
```

My Windows 10

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
```

Could it be because of the OpenSSH version difference causing the problem?

Update2:

I was able to update my OpenSSH in Windows 10 to the latest version thanks to an answer at a separate question here: https://superuser.com/a/1609071/830668

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
```

Restarted and tested, the error persists.

Comment: I ran into this exact issue just now and found that a hard restart fixed it. By that I mean shift-clicking Reboot in the Start menu and then selecting Shut down PC in the menu that shows after Windows initially says it's restarting your PC. Then wait for a bit and boot up again. Does that help you?

Comment: @Justastudent I run this on my laptop. So I always do a full shutdown anyways. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an issue with WSL2 interoperability if you have enabled systemd support in WSL.

Check whether `/etc/wsl.conf` specifies `systemd=true` in the `[boot]` section.

If systemd is enabled, you can refer to [Microsoft/WSL - Issue 8843](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8843) which suggests a mitigation to restore interoperability:

```bash
sudo sh -c 'echo :WSLInterop:M::MZ::/init:PF > /usr/lib/binfmt.d/WSLInterop.conf'
```